# Best solution for async chicken and egg story

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have been applying async best practices to all my libraries. Basically it means:

1. Only use async when it's truly async (libraries shouldn't lie)
2. Define a synchronous method if and only if you have a faster synchronous method that won’t dead lock.
3. Postfix all async methods with Async

I worked on a library that is synchronous by nature. This means it has only sync methods. If the user wants to run the work on a separate thread than the UI thread, they can do that themselves by using `Task.Factory` (responsibility of the caller).

However, inside a handler / method / extensibility point, we want to show the user a message box. This is an async method (for example, WinRT `ShowDialogAsync`). Then this gives us the following options:

**A. Move everything to async (so we have the option to use await in our handlers and don't block anything).**

```
public async Task MyMethodAsync()
{
    await _messageService.ShowAsync();
}
```

The advantage is that users can add async methods without having to use .Wait(). The downside is that we are lying as a library (it's not truly async).

I have considered making *everything* async, but I don't think that's a good idea either. It would make all libraries lie but prepare them *in case* we would need it. Remember that making everything async out of the box has a (small) performance impact as well.

**B. Inside the handler that requires user input, call .Wait()**

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    _messageService.ShowAsync().Wait();
}
```

The advantage is that this will allow us to use async code inside sync methods. But... it will never be callable from the UI-thread because the _messageService dispatches to the UI thread (but it cannot do that because it's still waiting for the method, resulting in a deadlock). This method **will** work when used inside a Task.Factory.Run block (but the responsibility is up to the end-user):

```
await Task.Factory.Run(() => MyMethod());
```

**The question**

I feel that both have pros and cons, but what would you choose? Let the library lie (A) or only allow the method to be called from a background thread (B)? Or maybe there are other options I've overseen.

If I go for A, it means I have to bump the major version every time (because it's actually a breaking change) whenever a user requests to convert a method to an async signature method.

Comment: Personally I would make the methods async and let the caller choose if they want to call it synchronously. Calling an async method without using await will force it to run synchronously without have to use a .Wait blocker.

Comment: *The downside is that we are lying as a library (it's not truly async).* What is not truely async? Isn't the message box invocation an async operation (as you stated)?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yes, but the whole library itself isn't async. It means we are just making it async for possible extensibility that might required async support?

Comment: Why not expose *this particular operation* as async? So what if the other methods are sync? Why refactor everything just because you have one async operation?

Comment: That's the whole point. This requirement is based on "what we need now". But there might be more methods that require async in the future. This leads me to the question on how to deal with such cases inside a library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Define a synchronous method if and only if you have a faster synchronous method that won’t dead lock.

I'd say "define a synchronous method if you have synchronous work to do". It doesn't matter how fast it is. The burden is on the caller to determine if it's too slow and they need to use `Task.Run`.

> However, inside a handler / method / extensibility point

If this is an Observer kind of extensibility, consider just using events or observables.

However, it sounds like you want more of a Strategy kind of extensibility, where your invoking code must wait for and/or change its behavior based on the result of the callback.

> I have considered making everything async, but I don't think that's a good idea either.

Async all the way is a guideline, not a strict command. It definitely applies in the 99% case, but this could be one of the exceptions. I would try not to make a library async just for the sake of a possibly-async Strategy pattern; I'd investigate other extension possibilities first. There is a valid argument for making the library async, if you view the Strategy callback as a dependency (the library would be async because its dependency is (possibly) async).

As you've discovered, there's no clean way to do sync-over-async. There are a few different hacks (such as blocking from a background thread), but you'll first need to decide whether you need to call your library from the UI thread.

If you do, then there's just two options: make the library async, or use a nested message loop. I strongly avoid nested message loops, especially in libraries; I'm just mentioning it for sake of completeness.

If you can impose on the user a requirement to only call the library from a non-UI thread, then you can apply other hacks. E.g., blocking the background thread.

There's not an easy solution, sorry.

As far as me personally... if the library needs an async Strategy, then I would lean towards making the library async. But it does depend on what kind of library it is, whether there were backwards-compatibility issues, etc. And the first thing I'd look into is a different kind of extensibility point.

Comment: Thanks. This was exactly what I was hoping to read. The extensibility points are indeed "strategy extensions", not "just-notify-the-user-extensions". We decided to use async events for these extensibility points. This allows a user to add async event handlers. This does require us to refactor all to async, but I think that's valid in this case.

Comment: @GeertvanHorrik: If you want to enable async Strategy events (where you need to know when the event completes), then I recommend using [deferrals](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/02/async-oop-5-events.html) (as I describe on my blog).

Comment: thanks, we were already using AsyncEventHandler (https://github.com/Catel/Catel/blob/e8c26d4a8a7d09e2799f24f7f547650c4bf79433/src/Catel.Core/Catel.Core.Shared/EventHandlers/AsyncEventHandler.cs), but since we were applying best practices to all libs, we were doubtful whether we should keep them. Will also look into the deferrals, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

as you can read here :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

> **Async All the Way**
>
> Asynchronous code reminds me of the story of a fellow who mentioned that the world was suspended in space and was immediately challenged by an elderly lady claiming that the world rested on the back of a giant turtle. When the man enquired what the turtle was standing on, the lady replied, “You’re very clever, young man, but it’s turtles all the way down!” As you convert synchronous code to asynchronous code, you’ll find that it works best if asynchronous code calls and is called by other asynchronous code—all the way down (or “up,” if you prefer). Others have also noticed the spreading behavior of asynchronous programming and have called it “contagious” or compared it to a zombie virus. Whether turtles or zombies, it’s definitely true that asynchronous code tends to drive surrounding code to also be asynchronous. This behavior is inherent in all types of asynchronous programming, not just the new async/await keywords.
>
> “Async all the way” means that you shouldn’t mix synchronous and asynchronous code without carefully considering the consequences. In particular, it’s usually a bad idea to block on async code by calling Task.Wait or Task.Result. This is an especially common problem for programmers who are “dipping their toes” into asynchronous programming, converting just a small part of their application and wrapping it in a synchronous API so the rest of the application is isolated from the changes. Unfortunately, they run into problems with deadlocks. After answering many async-related questions on the MSDN forums, Stack Overflow and e-mail, I can say this is by far the most-asked question by async newcomers once they learn the basics: “Why does my partially async code deadlock?”

Comment: Thanks. This basically means that *if* a user requests a change to make a method async (because they want it), I should make it async immediately? It believe that async all the way really works well for apps, but is that also the case for libraries? It feels weird exposing MyMethodAsync while, in fact, there is nothing async about it (yet).

Comment: if it uses await somewhere :make it async. the only excuse for async void would be an event.